# Create installable disk image from existing hard drive

Tags: linux, installation, sles, sysadmin

I installed a SLES 15 machine with a special library of my work. Since I need to install other machines with the same procedure, I want to "extract" the current installation to create an installable ISO file with the current configuration. How to do it if possible?

Many thanx

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use AutoYast :

1- Try to reproduce what you have done in order to get the actual configuration, that means try to write a **script** that will describe what you have done to get the actual configuration.

2- Get a **bootable** ISO installation media for SLES 15

3- Create your xml Kickstart configuration file, you will need to specify :

- Network configuration
- Filesystems partioning
- Users creation
- Packages that need to be installed.
- **pre** script section to execute before the installation.
- **post** script section to execute once the installation done, here you can use the script you wrote in the **step 1**

4- Use **jing** parser to validate the kickstart file.

5- Bundle the installation media with the kickstart file, it depends on the environment :

- Use a **PXE** server to make a network installation possible.
- Or, use a **media device**, like cdrom or flash usb.
- Or, if it's a virtualized environment, just mount it on the targeted
  VM and then change the grub/uefi  entry to use the kickstart file
  with : **inst.ks** attribute.

6- Test first this procedure on a test server then deploy on the other nodes.

Here is the full documentation you will need to implement this solution [AutoYast Doc](https://doc.opensuse.org/projects/autoyast/#Profile.Format)